# Ubuntu 20 battery percentage

Tags: 20.04, battery

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 20.04. I have found out that when the battery percentage is lower than a value such as 35 ,there is a big deviation of percentage.For instance,before 15 minutes I saw that I had 31% battery WITHOUT charge it and I saw the red led of my laptop blinking ,so when I put the cable in order to charge it,I saw that I had 4% (not 31).So,my question is ,does anybody know why there is this big deviation of percentage?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably just the hardware you are working on, not Ubuntu. There is a constant battery voltage monitor which is the only indicator to go by for the hardware. It is very difficult to translate a certain battery tension into power capacity.

Comment: If you have an old battery then probably its time to get a new one.